# Chrome extension - show content box in page like Analytics app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Google Analytics Chrome extension can display additional content with charts on current web. E.g.

[image: Page Analytics (by Google)]

How to open such window automatically?

Or this is just html injection to current page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is called in page analytics. Install [Page analytics chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-analytics-by-google/fnbdnhhicmebfgdgglcdacdapkcihcoh?hl=en)

For data to reflect, you need to be logged in to your google analytics account in chrome, and browse the site url in the same window.

Comment: I'm looking how to implement such behaviour (with content not related to this particular example plugin), not how to install this plugin ;)

Comment: Ohhh, my bad :)